# CSS: Auto filling cell tables and ways to build a good layout?

Tags: html, css, resize, fill

Hi all and thanks in advance for your help.

I'm pretty new to the CSS, and I would like to have a good input to start building and learning the fastest way possible. I'm already doing some CSS tests myself. Right on the question.

this is the relative css code (I put it on pastebin because it's a bit long)
[CSS CODE](http://pastebin.com/sUdUzKjL)

As you can see in the code, the 2 tables showing up in the image, have a background and I had to set their size manually with

```
width:100px;
height:120px;
```

in the td.menuleft and td.menucenter classes.

**1° Question**

How do I make automatically resizing cells?

For example i want to say:

Make table tag wide 100% of the page width, then let me make classes for  cell tables that are a certain percentage of the table width.

Example

[Pic of my work, and how I want to make it like](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/8549/04b107766cc847e1bafae30.png)

This way it will be easy to make up tables into  tags to automatically fill pages. I've seen something about positioning (relative, absolute) but I didn't managed to make it work.

**2° question**

What's the best way to structure a web page with css in general? It's ok to do like I said, a div, with tables inside and place every element in a table like manner?

Or can you give me any guide step to step on how to do a particular template?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to learn how to make good and effective design that are also considered any worth by search engines, then don't use tables for layouts. tables are there for showing table data, not layout. Use instead divs and start reading about positions, displays, floats.

That is the way you want to go

Comment: this is better left as a comment on the question, no? It doesn't really provide an actual solution to his problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip though, very useful. Any good guide or example about using divs in the way you said?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the tds to be a certain percentage width, they will be the percentage of the parent. so:

```
table {
    width: 100px;
}

tr {
    width: 100% /* Will be 100px */
}

td.quarter {
    width: 25%; /* Will be 25px */
}

td.half {
    width: 50%; /* Will be 50px */
}
```

And I agree with the previous poster, do NOT use tables for layouts. Not that you are doing that here. But for layouts stick to divs and such.

Comment: Nice, but how I can tell the table to automatically adapt to the page size?
For example if I have a 1000px large browser page i want table to be the same size or a little smaller, how i can tell css to automatically detect and do it?

I want it to works on pages with different sizes

Comment: You can use a percentage for the table width as well. You can have it take up 100% of the page.